# IPython Notebook cells with listings

Tags: listings, code

I would like to include in my document some code examples that look like the IPython Notebook cells in this image:

[image]

I have produced something that looks a bit like it with the code below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    escapechar=¢,
    language=python,
    frame=single,
    frameround=tttt,
    showstringspaces=false,
    backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray}
}
\newcommand*{\ipythonprompt}[1]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\textbf{In [#1]:}\hspace{1em}}}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Here are two IPython cells:
\begin{lstlisting}
¢\ipythonprompt{1}¢ n = 10
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{lstlisting}
¢\ipythonprompt{2}¢ for i in range(n):
    print('i = ', i)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

But I have a couple of issues:

- The corners aren't quite right: they're a bit wonky and too rounded;
- The prompts `In [1]:` etc are in the margin, but I'd like them in the body of the text, with the gray cell area to the right of them.

Can anyone suggest how I might achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package and its interaction with `listings`:

[image]

The code (adjust the settings according to your needs):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}

% the space reserved between for the ``In'' numbers and the code
\newlength\inwd
\setlength\inwd{1.3cm}

\newcounter{ipythcntr}

\newtcblisting{ipythonnb}[1][\theipythcntr]{
  enlarge left by=\inwd,
  width=\linewidth-\inwd,
  enhanced,
  boxrule=0.4pt,
  colback=light-gray,
  listing only,
  top=0pt,
  bottom=0pt,
  overlay={
    \node[
      anchor=north east,
      text width=\inwd,
      font=\footnotesize\ttfamily\color{blue!50!black},
      inner ysep=2mm,
      inner xsep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt
      ] 
      at (frame.north west)
      {\stepcounter{ipythcntr}In [#1]:};
  }
  listing options={
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    language=python,
    escapechar=¢,
    showstringspaces=false,
  },
}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

Here are two IPython cells:
\begin{ipythonnb}
n = 10
\end{ipythonnb}

\begin{ipythonnb}
for i in range(n):
    print('i = ', i)
\end{ipythonnb}

\begin{ipythonnb}[13]
n = 10
\end{ipythonnb}

\end{document}
```

The optional argument for the `ipythonnb` environment allows to manually control the numbering in the `In` part.